# Flex - Colocar elemento en espacio que sobra

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Mi duda es que quiero colocar el div ***three*** justo debajo del div ***two*** y de esta manera el div ***one*** se ajustaría al alto de box, pero ese espacio(el de debajo del div two) esta "reservado" para el div ***two*** (si no me equivoco) sé que podría añadir un div que contuviera el ***two*** y el ***three*** y que ocuparan ese espacio. Pero quiero saber si es posible hacerlo sin ese contenedor para luego según cambie el tamaño de la caja(responsive) poder cambiar el orden de los elementos con la propiedad "order". Seguro  que me estoy dejando algo atrás y no se el que xD.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.box {
      background: red;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: flex-start;
      height: 300px;
    }

    .one{
      align-self: stretch;
      background: orange;
      flex-basis: 25%;
    }

    .two {
      background: yellow;
      flex-basis: 75%;
    }

    .three{
      background: blue;
      flex-basis: 75%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Es una buena primera pregunta, pero aun así te recomiendo completar el [tour] para tener una mejor idea general de cómo se pregunta y se responde. *Un consejo*: No es necesario dar las gracias ni pedir perdón al preguntar, aquí nos gusta ir *al grano* y que votes positivo una respuesta es la forma de dar las gracias a quien la escribió.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, tendré muy en cuenta tus consejos para la siguiente vez que plantee una pregunta, voy a echarle un ojo al enlace que me has puesto para conocer mejor como funciona todo en SOes. Buen día!

Answer (score 8):

El fallo es que estaba usando `flex` como `row` (por defecto), pero si utilizo la propiedad `flex-direction: column` puedo hacer todo lo que quería...

Llevaba desde ayer dándole vueltas y ahora leyendo mi pregunta me acabo de dar cuenta que estaba planteándola mal desde un principio por como usaba el flex.

Dejo la solución por si le sirve a alguien:

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.one {
  align-self: stretch;
  background: orange;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 75%;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No pidas perdón por hacer una pregunta y luego encontrar la respuesta, esto es algo bienvenido en SOes.

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta, creando un fragmento ejecutable (al igual que en la pregunta). Es más útil que una imagen.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Excelente comienzo. Si algun dia quisieras pasar por el [chat] para contarnos como fue tu primera experiencia por aqui haciendo tu primera pregunta, bienvenido seas.

Comment: Coincido con Pablo y los demás. Da gusto ver usuarios nuevos con esa predisposición y te agradezco que hayas puesto la respuesta por si sirve a otros. Bienvenido.